# Track if LUIS intent has already been triggered

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

How can i track if LUIS intent has already been triggered  ??
Channel used: Facebook

**Scenario**
User : Audi TT details
Bot  : [car details....]
User : Thank you
Bot  : Would you like us to contact you? (provide yes or no prompt)
User : [select options (yes or no)]...
**Next time same user chats...or later in same conversation**
User : do you have parts for Audi TT?
Bot  : Yes, we have the following parts available
User : Great thanks!
Bot  : Glad to help -> Bot must not provide ***"Would you like us to contact you?"*** prompt again

I'm using LUIS intent to detect if user is saying 'thank you' and then trigger the prompt. How can I track if the intent has already been triggered

```
[LuisIntent ("Gratitude")]  
public async Task Gratitude(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)  
{               
    if( intent_has_not_been_triggered_for_user)
       PromptDialog.Choice(context,
             ResumeAfterGratitude,
             new[] { "Yes", "No"},
             "Thank you. Would you like us to contact you?",
             promptStyle: PromptStyle.Keyboard, attempts: 4
           );

   else  
      await context.PostAsync("Glad to help");  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `context.UserData` to store data associated with a user.

In your case, you can set the value in case the value is not present in `UserData` by using a key, something like `GratitudeTriggered`, and every time check if the key exists in the User data. You can also customize the logic as per your needs like to match a particular value, existence of the value, etc.

Sample code:

```
[LuisIntent("Gratitude")]
public async Task Gratitude(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> message, LuisResult result)
{
    if (context.UserData.TryGetValue("GratitudeTriggered", out bool gratitudeTriggered))
    {
        //Triggered for the first time, store it in UserData that the Gratitude is triggered
        context.UserData.SetValue("GratitudeTriggered", "yes");

        PromptDialog.Choice(context,
              ResumeAfterGratitude,
              new[] { "Yes", "No" },
              "Thank you. Would you like us to contact you?",
              promptStyle: PromptStyle.Keyboard, attempts: 4
            );
    }
    else
        await context.PostAsync("Glad to help");
}
```